# Can we add multiple success_url's for the stripe subscriptions?

Tags: reactjs, stripe-payments

I am new to stripe integration and I'm looking for a way to have multiple **success_url** for the subscriptions. Currently I have like 3 subscriptions with the names, Plan-A, Plan-B & Plan-C. And when an user proceeds with stripe payment for Plan-A, then success_url should show a thank you page saying the user now has Plan-A subscriptions and its features and so on for Plan-B & Plan-C. Can anyone help me to understand on how I can achieve the multiple success_url with reactjs.

Need to add multiple success_url for the stripe subscriptions

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you are checking out. With Stripe.js you can send your desired return URL when creating the [payment intent](https://stripe.com/docs/js/payment_intents/confirm_payment):

```
stripe.confirmPayment({
  elements,
  confirmParams: {
    // Return URL where the customer should be redirected after the PaymentIntent is confirmed.
    return_url: 'https://example.com',
  },
})
.then(function(result) {
  if (result.error) {
    // Inform the customer that there was an error.
  }
});
```

If you using the Stripe hosted Checkout you can [modify the success URL](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/custom-success-page#modify-success-url) to include the session ID which you can use to then retrieve the [session data](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/retrieve).

Ex: `http://yoursite.com/order/success?session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}`

That being said it depends on what you are doing/showing on success. If you simply want to say "thanks for buying plan A (or B)" then you could store that in the state. But if you are doing more complex stuff then fetching the session data is prob the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout Session doesn't support multiple URLs in `success_url` parameter.

Two possible ways to redirect to `success_url` of corresponding plan.

1. When you create the Checkout Session, set the `success_url` to the URL of the price plan since you would have known the plan in `line_items` at this time
2. Append [`session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}"`](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/custom-success-page#modify-success-url) in the query parameter of `success_url`. When the customer is redirected to the `success_url`, check the Checkout Session ID and find out the plan that is set this Checkout Session in your database, then display the success page of the plan.